# How to configure nginx's default.conf

Tags: nginx, dns, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm trying to configure `default.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` to show a simple landing page located at `/home/ubuntu/project-source/company/entry/index.html`.

The domains are set up correctly as far as I know to point to the server

```
A: test24.company.io -> <aws-elastic-IP>
```

**default.conf:**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        root   /home/ubuntu/project-source/company/entry;
    }
}

server {
    server_name test24.company.io www.test24.company.io;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test24.company.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test24.company.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = test24.company.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen      80;
    server_name test24.company.io www.test24.company.io;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Additional question: the project will run 2 processes on 2 subdomains lets say `sub1` and `sub2` and they will run on  `localhost:3001` and `localhost:3002` respectively, how do I configure `default.conf` to point/proxy to these processes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after many days and hours breaking my head I came to this solution:

1. On GoDaddy's DNS I added these records:
   `A: test24.company.io      -> <aws-elastic-IP>`
   `A: sub1.test24.company.io -> <aws-elastic-IP>`
   `A: sub2.test24.company.io -> <aws-elastic-IP>`
   ***note:*** *All 3 records point to the same elastic IP, there is no need to set an individual elastic IP for each subdomain.*
2. The nginx conf file is configured as follows:
   https://gist.github.com/ahmed-abdelazim/b3536c1780afc4215ef57633bbe77a88

[This](https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0) post is a very useful guide on setting nginx proxies for different ports on your server.

All the rest in the nginx config file is generated by certbot, which also managed the redirect from http to https.

*note to mods: I cannot seem to format the code of the GitHubGist in this answer for some reason.*

Answer (score 1):

first use this way to redirect HTTP to HTTPS

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.com www.example.com; 
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Second Your server root not included in SSL server it should include

```
root   /home/ubuntu/project-source/company/entry;
```

Third
You can add what you want of apps on different ports. just copy paste whole server code and change desired values like root location and PORT

after end of edit save and restart server

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Your way of redirecting http to https is correct but I left it out of my solution as the redirects were generated by certbot itself so no need to manually add it.